# How to load data from distinct .json file to List<T>, C#?

Tags: c#, json.net

My problem is that I want to take data from .json file, and initialize with it a list of objects.

I have my .json file:

```json
{
  "Card1": {
    "Name": "Kyiv",
    "price": 200,
    "taxes": 150
  },
  "Card2": {
    "Name": "Kamiyanske",
    "price": 150,
    "taxes": 100
  },
  "Card3": {
    "Name": "Rivne",
    "price": 150,
    "taxes": 100
  }
}
```

I want to take this data and fill in objects, and create a list of them

This is my try to do so

```
List<Card> LoadJson()
{
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("C:\\fileName.json"))
    {
        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
        var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Card>>(json);
        return items;
    }
}

var Cards = LoadJson();
Console.WriteLine(Cards[0].Name);
```

But every time I get an exception:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WpfApp1.Card]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])

Comment: Your JSON can't deserialize to a list, because it's an object, not an array. You can go to a Dictionary<string, Card> however. By the way, you originally tagged this question as System.Text.Json. Thats a completely different library from Newtonsoft JSON.NET.

Comment: You can try do deserialize to the `Dictionary<string, Card>` and then take `Values` from this dictionary and convert it to `List<Card>`.

Answer (score 3):

As a matter of fact you have a json object that fits a Dictionary, not a List. You can parse json and convert it to list in one line

```
List<Card> items = JObject.Parse(json).Properties().Select(jo =>jo.Value.ToObject<Card>() ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom `JsonConverter` something like this:

```
class CardListConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(List<Card>);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return (from JProperty prop in JObject.Load(reader).Properties()
                select prop.Value.ToObject<Card>())
                .ToList();
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then you can use the above converter like this

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = { new CardListConverter() } };
var cards = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Card>>(json, settings);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a very practical question and I actually had this kind of json payload at work.

I use **dynamic** object to process the payload as below,

```
           using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("C:\\fileName.json"))
           {
                string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                dynamic items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

                List<Card> cards = new List<Card>();

                foreach(var item in items)
                {
                    var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item.Value);
                    Card card = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Card>(jsonString);
                    cards.Add(card);
                }

                return cards;
            }
```

Comment: offtopic, but I keep seeing questions with similar JSON structures on SO. Do people that make these don't understand how JSON arrays work, or is there another reason why they make it like that?

Comment: Well, technically, the JSON itself is not wrong, and you could imagine that it might be serialised from an object with properties Card1, Card2...for whatever reason. As a data consumer, I wish I could have an easy life, but we live in the real world.